# error in converting string to datetime asp.net and sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datetime, type-conversion

I have a problem when converting a `string` to a `datetime`.

I have a table called `student`...

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[student]
(
  [s_no] [int] IDENTITY(100,1) NOT NULL,
  [s_id]  AS ('STU_'+CONVERT([varchar](10),[s_no])) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
  [s_fname] [varchar](50) NULL,
  [s_lname] [varchar](50) NULL,
  [s_address] [varchar](50) NULL,
  [s_mobile] [varchar](20) NULL,
  [s_mail] [varchar](50) NULL,
  [s_dop] [datetime] NULL,
  [s_status] [varchar](25) NULL DEFAULT ('active'),
  [s_password]  AS (substring(CONVERT([varchar](225),newid()),(1),(8))),
  [s_joindate] [datetime] NULL,
  [s_gender] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
  [s_country] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
  [s_mname] [varchar](50) NULL,
  [previousschool] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
  [pschooladress] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
  [schoolgrade] [int] NULL,
  [schoolleavingdate] [datetime] NULL,
  [imgpath] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
  [ID] [nvarchar](50)  NULL
)
```

... and all I want to do is to insert data from a webform.

```cs
string insrtstudent 
    = @"insert into student (
          s_fname,
          s_lname,
          s_address,
          s_mobile,
          s_mail,
          s_dop,
          s_status,
          s_joindate,
          s_gender,
          s_country,
          s_mname,
          previousschool,
          pschooladress,
          schoolgrade,
          schoolleavingdate,
          imgpath,
          ID
        ) values (
          @fname,
          @lname,
          @add,
          @mob,
          @mail,
          @dob,
          @join,
          @status,
          @gender,
          @country,
          @midname,
          @previous,
          @scholladd,
          @schoolgrade,
          @schooldate,
          @img,
          @id)";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insrtstudent, con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@fname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Fnametxt.Text.ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@lname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lnametxt.Text.ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@add", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = addtxt.Text.ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@mob", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = mobtxt.Text.ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@mail", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = mailtxt.Text.ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@status", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dropstatus.SelectedValue.ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@dob", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse(dob.ToString());
cmd.Parameters.Add("@join", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse( joindate.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@gender", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = gender;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@midname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = midnametxt.Text.ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@country", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddcountry.SelectedValue.ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@previous", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = prevscholtxt.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@scholladd", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = PREVADTXT.Text; 
cmd.Parameters.Add("@schoolgrade", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(sgradtxt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@schooldate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value=DateTime.Parse(schodate.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@img", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "st_imgs/"+FileName;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = IDTXT.Text;

con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

I also tried...

```
         Convert.ToDateTime
```

...but it does not work 
I have the error...

```
          Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

I am sorry if this question has been asked before, but I searched for hours and I could not find a solution.

I appreciate any help
and thanks.

Comment: what does the datetime string look like?

Comment: it look like mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: can you show what it actually was? Also, what country is this in, or IOW, what culture/language is the OS using?

Comment: country Egypt  & language of OS is English

Comment: Can you share with us the values of dob,  joindate and schodate that you are trying to convert to DateTime? The values of these variables might not be in the right format for a DateTime.Parse() . In the webform you might first want to validate the date inputs before inserting the records.

Comment: ok joindate and schooldate came from datapicker for example 12/28/2015,11/2/2014 and dop it is string from 3 dropdown for example 11/11/1999

Comment: @banksy My guess, is that being in Egypt, even though the OS is english, that the date separators are other than slash `/` and/or that the arrangement of the date parts are other than MM/DD/YYYY. So the correct `Convert.ToDateTime` to use is the one that takes a `string` and an `IFormatProvider`. See the example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xk1h71t(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @banksy You could also use `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.ParseExact`